# Azure VSTS deployment related issue (Deploying a laravel app)

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-pipelines

I'm using azure to deploy my web application, Laravel application
laravel uses site\wwwroot\public as entry point
For that reason I'm using "site\wwwroot\public" in Virtual applications and directories under application settings
Where can I find the setting of the location where the code will deploy that will arrive from VSTS (deployment source)

[Application settings on Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghA1i.png)

Right now this is the link where whenever my project arrives from VSTS is deployed
I don't want that, I want it to be deployed in "site\wwwroot\" yet keep entry point of application same as above in bullet

Comment: What's the requirement that you need to set the root level to site\wwwroot\public but need to deploy app to site\wwwroot? You can set the root directory to site\wwwroot and add a virtual directory (public) in azure portal (Select the app service > Application settings)

Comment: How do you deploy the application from VSTS to Azure? Use VSTS build or  configure the deployment from Azure directly?